# Custom filtering of GitLab merge requests

Tags: gitlab

I have built a script that uses the GitLab API to extract all open merge requests in a project and group them by number of upvotes. I'd like to create links so my team mates can view the MR groups on the GitLab UI.

I'm aware that "Upvotes" is not one of the default attributes that GitLab supports filtering by, but I am wondering if anybody knows any tricks as to how I could create a link that will filter merge requests by number of upvotes?

Alternatively, since I have all the merge requests ID's, is it possible to filter by multiple ID's? I'm aware you can search for a single MR ID by using #. So ID 219 can be found by searching #219. But is there a way I could search for multiple ID's at once. Initially I thought I could just use "OR" keyword or "||" but GitLab search doesn't seem to have this functionality built in.

Any thoughts are appreciated. Even just confirming that this is not possible would be a great help! Thanks

Comment: I think issues do support this kind of filter. Maybe consider associating your MRs with issues and upvote the issues instead?